# Tips for golfing in Pascal

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing code in Pascal?

I know this is a tricky language very few people use this but I would like to know any tips from the professionals out there :)

I'm looking for tips that can reduce code size (every byte counts!) with special functions or even crazy combinations

Please post each tip as a separate answer, and avoid tips not specific to Pascal (e.g. remove whitespace, etc.)

Answer (score 7):

### Avoid `Integer`

```pascal
VAR var1: Integer; (* Signed, 16 bits in TP7, 32 bits in FPC, It costs 7 bytes. *)
    var2: Word;    (* Unsigned 16 bit, works in most cases. *)
    var3: Int64;   (* Signed 64 bits, Only available in FPC. *)
    var4: 0..9;    (* TP7: same as ShortInt (-128..127), FPC: same as Byte (0..255) *)
```

### Use `^J` for line break

```pascal
WriteLn('abc');Write('def');
Write('abc',chr(10),'def');
Write('abc'#10'def');
Write('abc'^J'def');        (* Both in TP7 and FPC *)
```

`^J` is two bytes `^` followed by `J`, not single byte for `Ctrl-J`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Numbers before keywords

```pascal
for i:=69 to 420 do writeln(i);
for i:=69to 420do writeln(i);
```

save you 2 byte on for loop

Comment: NB: Some compilers will _reject_ this, so you _will need_ to write “compiled with <compiler>” when handing in solutions. The ISO standards 7185 (“Standard Pascal”) and 10206 “Extended Pascal” expect a token separator between keywords and numbers.

Answer (score 3):

#### Variable declaration of same type

```pascal
var i:word;j:word;
var i,j:word;
```

Furthermore, all variables can be declared in one `var` block:

```pascal
var i,j:word;a,b,c:string;x,y:char;
```

Answer (score 3):

### use (already existing) parentheses as token separators

A loop determining the length of `input` without processing it

```pascal
while not EOF do begin get(input);i:=i+1 end
```

can be rearranged into

```pascal
while not EOF do begin i:=i+1;get(input)end
```

Similarly in expressions

```pascal
if ord(c)=32 then
```

is the same as

```pascal
if 32=ord(c)then
```

Since this only saves you one character, it does not make sense to introduce *extra* parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

### use `string` as an `array[1‥n] of 0‥ord(maxChar)`

In Pascal `string` literals may contain arbitrary values from the domain of `char`.
Even `chr(0)` is permitted.
The only *illegal* component is the value denoting a newline (in ASCII `chr(10)` [“line feed”] and/or `chr(13)` [“carriage return”]).
In other words, multi-line `string` literals are not allowed.
Furthermore the string delimiting character `'` (ASCII `chr(39)`) needs to be escaped (conventionally `''`).
Example:

```pascal
program stringArrayDemo(output);
begin
    writeLn(ord(('€Bÿ')[3]))
end.
```

Since it’s not properly displayed, the above string literal consists of the following four characters (ordinal value in hexadecimal base):

```
80 42 FF 12
```

Therefore the above `program` will print `255` as it’s the third character’s ordinal value.
Obviously in your challenge at hand the constant index `3` will be some *variable* expression and the `string` literal will have different values.

Since the `maxChar` value introduced in ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” documents an implementation characteristic, it is imperative that your solution mentions the processor used.
The above `program` will work adequately if compiled with the GNU Pascal Compiler (GPC) or the Free Pascal Compiler (FPC).

Answer (score 2):

### prefer `repeat … until …` loops over `while … do begin … end` loops

Consideration for *guaranteed* iteration count ≥ 1:
If the loop body of a `while` loop contains *multiple* statements, i. e. *is surrounded* by a proper `begin … end`, you may consider turning it into a `repeat … until` loop where the `repeat … until` by itself constitutes a `begin … end` frame.

```pascal
while condition do begin statement;statement end
```

becomes

```pascal
repeat statement;statement until not condition
```

Since a `repeat` loop’s body is executed *at least* once, this works fine if it’s *guaranteed* that the `while`’s loop body would be executed at least once, too.
If `condition` can legitimately cause *zero* iterations, this tip does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

#### Iterating over the alphabet (or other contiguous ASCII range)

Iterate over the string:

```pascal
var c:char;begin
for c in'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'do writeln(c);
```

Or, use an ASCII range (uppercase alphabet)

```pascal
var j:word;begin
for j:=65to 90do writeln(chr(j));
```

**BUT! Here's the most compact approach**, for [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gsTk7M0U0rSP7/vyyxSCHLKjkjscg6KTU9M08hLR8kYKtsZlqSr2xpkJKvUF6UWZKak6eRpZmal6Kn8P8/AA):

```pascal
var j:char;begin for j:=#65to#90do writeln(j)end.
```

Comment: It should be highlighted that this is a Delphi extension. It is also supported by the FreePascal Compiler (since 2.4.2). ISO standard 10206 ”Extended Pascal“ only provides `for … in` for sets.

Comment: wont `var j:char;begin for j:=#65to#90do writeln(j)end. ` simply work?

Answer (score 1):

### Use the short form of `if` and `for`

If your `if` condition/ `for` loop only does one statement, omit `begin` and `end`.

`if <boolean> then begin <statement>;end;`

`if <boolean> then <statement>;` ✅

`for <condition> do begin <statement>;end;`

`for <condition> do <statement>;` ✅

You can also string them together, e.g.

`for <condition> do if <boolean> then <statement>;`

Comment: This is a bit of a misconception: Both `for` and `if` require one statement. The `begin … end` frame represents one statement. There is no “short” or “long” form of either of them.

Comment: The formal construct (e.g. `if x>y then begin;inc(k);writeln(a);end;`) allows one *or more* statements. But if there's only one statement, `begin` and `end` are optional.. maybe this is too elemental

Answer (score 1):

#### Prefer `upcase` over `lowercase`

That's 3 whole bytes. Handy for case-insensitive string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

### use `index` for `in` membership test

**Introduction**:
All Pascal variants support at least to some extent the `in` membership operator (in mathematical notation ∊).
Extended Pascal, ISO standard 10206, introduces the `index` function.
It requires two `char` or `string` arguments (any combination thereof).

```pascal
index(sample, pattern)
```

The `index` function returns the index of the first complete occurrence of `pattern` in `sample`.
If no such index exists, `0` is returned (an *invalid* index for any `string`).

**Application**:
The `index` function can be utilized to abbreviate `set`-membership operations.
For example

```pascal
c in['X','Y','Z']       { `c` is a variable possessing the data type `char` }
```

becomes

```pascal
index('XYZ',c)>0
```

**Synergies**:
You can combine this with the [`string` as `array[1‥n] of 0‥ord(maxChar)`](/a/254108/) tip.
For example

```pascal
index(')/;CGaek•—§³µãåéïñ', chr(241)) > 0
```

performs a test whether `chr(241)` is a [Ramanujan prime](https://oeis.org/A104272) less than 256.
Note, the `string` literal consists of 23 `char` values and are not properly displayed on this site.

**Dialects**:
Delphi users want to use `pos`.
The Free Pascal Compiler supports [`pos`](https://www.FreePascal.org/docs-html/current/rtl/system/pos.html), too.