# Counting Letters in a String

Tags: code-golf, string, array

Write a program or function that takes in a string and outputs a count of each modern English alphabet letter in the string, case-insensitive.

Input: A string consisting of printable ASCII characters (code points 32-126).

Output: A list of pairs, where each pair consists of a letter and its count in the string. The list should be sorted in alphabetical order by letter. The list shall omit letters occurring zero times.

### Test Cases

```
Input: "hello world"
Output: [('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('h', 1), ('l', 3), ('o', 2), ('r', 1), ('w', 1)]

Input: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Output: [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 3), ('f', 1), ('g', 1), ('h', 2), ('i', 1), ('j', 1), ('k', 1), ('l', 1), ('m', 1), ('n', 1), ('o', 4), ('p', 1), ('q', 1), ('r', 2), ('s', 1), ('t', 2), ('u', 2), ('v', 1), ('w', 1), ('x', 1), ('y', 1), ('z', 1)]
```

Code Golf Specifics:

Your goal is to write the shortest possible code in bytes that correctly solves the problem. Your code must be able to handle any valid input within the given constraints. Note that your code should treat uppercase and lowercase letters as equivalent.

Good luck!

Comment: I suggest test cases involving more non-letters than just spaces.

Comment: let me think of something... I would appreciate if you propose some test case

Comment: 90% sure this is a dupe.

Comment: Is outputting a `Map` acceptable?

Comment: not sure what is a Map @Unmitigated

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz A collection of key-value pairs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @Unmitigated yes its allowed

Comment: Test cases don't count the space characters or the capital T

Comment: [closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19068/display-number-of-occurrences-for-every-character-in-an-input-string)

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of, @mathcat. To me, this is sufficiently similar to be a dupe but my vote is a hammer, so I won't swing it yet 'til we see what others think.

Comment: @Shaggy mine isn't, I'll vtc then.

Comment: Treating uppercase and lower case letters as equivalent is IMO a signficant difference from the other challenge. I don't like either challenge personally, but the dupe target is pretty dated, with rules and format I wouldn't expect to see today and I'd prefer if that were closed as a dupe of this.

Comment: Also, it's best for a specification not to be inferred from test cases, so it would bear mentioning that counts of 0 are omitted. Unless that's opt-out, of course!

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. This challenge requires a more-than-trivial amount of work, and the existing answers can't be minimally changed to achieve the expected output. The output format itself is also completely incompatible. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It’s not a duplicate, but _derivative_ of [display number of occurrences for every character in an input string](/q/19068). This task is essentially just asking to _extend_ answers of said “base task” by injecting some kind of “lettercase altering function” and _discarding_ tuples of non-alphabet characters. Input still consists of blanks, punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ǍɽĊs
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHjcm9xIpzIiwiIiwiXCJUaGUgcXVpY2sgYnJvd24gZm94IGp1bXBzIG92ZXIgdGhlIGxhenkgZG9nXCIiXQ==)

**How it works**:

```
ǍɽĊs
Ǎɽ    Remove non-alphabetical chars and lowercase
  Ċ   Count of each element
   s  Sorted
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 60 bytes

```python
lambda s:{c:s.lower().count(c)for c in s.lower()if'`'<c<'{'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3bXISc5NSEhWKraqTrYr1cvLLU4s0NPWS80vzSjSSNdPyixSSFTLzFOBSmWnqCeo2yTbq1eq1EDN2FhRlAhWnaSh5pObk5OsolOcX5aQoKmlqQuQXLIDQAA)

Returns a dictionary. Suggested by *@JonathanAllan*.

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 70 bytes

```python
lambda s:sorted((c,s.lower().count(c))for c in{*s.lower()}if'`'<c<'{')
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY33XISc5NSEhWKrYrzi0pSUzQ0knWK9XLyy1OLNDT1kvNL80o0kjU10_KLFJIVMvOqteCStZlp6gnqNsk26tXqmhDTdhYUZQLVp2koeaTm5OTrKJTnF-WkKCppQuUXLIDQAA)

Returns a sorted list of tuples.

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 75 bytes

```python
lambda s:sorted({*zip(x:=[*filter(str.isalpha,s.lower())],map(x.count,x))})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3vXMSc5NSEhWKrYrzi0pSUzSqtaoyCzQqrGyjtdIyc0pSizSKS4r0MosTcwoyEnWK9XLyy4FimpqxOrmJQHV6yfmleSU6FZqatZoQI3cWFGXmlWikaSh5pObk5OsolOcX5aQoKmlC5RcsgNAA)

Returns a sorted list of tuples.

##### Commented

```python
lambda s: sorted(          # Define an anonymous function which takes a string, s,
                           # and returns a sorted version of the following:
  (c, s.lower().count(c))  #  a tuple of the character, c, and its count
                           #  in the lowercase version of s
  for c in {*s.lower()}    #  for each character, c, in the lowercase version of s uniquified
  if '`' < c < '{' )       #  but only keep it if it is between the characters
                           #  '`' (right before 'a') and '{' (right after 'z')
                           #  i.e., it's alphabetic
```

```python
lambda s: sorted(          # Define an anonymous function which takes a string, s,
                           # and returns a sorted version of the following:
  {*zip(                   #  a uniquified version of two iterables zipped together:
    x := [*filter(         #   filter by
      str.isalpha,         #   is the character in the alphabet
      s.lower()            #   apply to a lowercase version of s
    )],                    #   and store in x
    map(x.count, x) )})    #   the counts of each character in x
```

Comment: OP appears to allow a dictionary as output in the comments, which would make this only \$60\$ with `lambda s:{c:s.lower().count(c)for c in s.lower()if'\`'<c<'{'}`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan that wouldn't be sorted though, would it? Adding the sort would be [76 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3fXISc5NSEhWKrYrzi0pSUzSqk62K9XLyy1OLNDT1kvNL80o0kjXT8osUkhUy8xTgUplp6gnqNsk26tXqtXqZJam5xRqamhAzdxYUZQJ1pWkoeaTm5OTrKJTnF-WkKCrB5BcsgNAA)

Comment: No, it wouldn't be sorted, but *if* they allow [what was linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) then a plain dictionary is acceptable.

Comment: @JonathanAllan alright, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>151</s> <s>142</s> 135 bytes

```java
s->{var m=new java.util.TreeMap();for(var c:s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").toCharArray())m.merge(c|=32,1,(a,b)->(int)a+(int)b);return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU/BTsMwDD3Tr7B6SqCNBNzoVmlC4sRO24lpSG6XdunSJLhpRzf27aUbOyAh4Ytlv@fn9yrsMK42u0HVzpKHapxF65UWRWtyr6wRt0nwB5yjSwLXZlrlkGtsGpijMnAMYKzGox/3L1eBycKTMmU0UtzkeYuEuZcUwas1ZZpCMR2aOD12SFBPjdz/@rIkKccjxpPCEjsz8qdGkHQacznTmoWrd4wPs/htHUZhyIW3Z/0ZEfaM81rUkkrJ8q/p40N0HzGMMh6nTBnP8e7SMp6Q9C0ZqJPTkFzsX2NdU3RWbaAew7GfGKs1IJUNPwY3i77xsha29cKNkNeGFQKd0z0Lt1JrC3tLehNynvxPXm4lfLQq30FGdm@gsJ9QtbVrwHaSwI@wxkMPG1texM4uT8Fp@AY)

Saved 15 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210).

Comment: You can remove `<Character,Long>` and use `1,(a,b)->(int)a+(int)b` instead for -7 bytes. And you can also changed the `.chars().forEach(c->` with `(char)c` to a regular `for(var c:s....toCharArray())` and `c` for another -2 bytes: [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/5n73a4um).

Comment: Oh, and -6 more bytes by using `c|=32` instead of `c`, adding the case-insensitive flag `(?i)` to the regex, and removing the `.toLowerCase()`: [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/m3rb6yup). :) ([Relevant tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42672/52210))

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice, I'd forgotten about those bitwise tricks with ASCII. Actually it seems `[^a-zA-Z]` is shorter than `(?i)[^a-z]` though.

Answer (score 5):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 66 bytes

```
ascii_downcase|reduce match("[a-z]";"g").string as $c({};.[$c]+=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pc7ZQoJAGEDhe5/ij6ggg7K9yMr2fTFbiWycGWFQGJgZXFB79Mh36Nx@NydMiwJJzFiT8H6MkaRjQUmGKURI4cDQXGTlnuZovmbaUgkW@4Ak6NgYTRzb1bFXrlbMooAZbVafm18wzMXykmUvr1RW19Y3Nre2d3adver@wWHt6Pjk9Oz84vLq@ub27v7hsf7UeH55fXv/cD@9r@Y3amFC237Awk43inmSCqmyXn8wzEfjyU@pEVBIM4Y70BLTUWjzAYRZlFACvEcFqKl3UT4Ewn27VPtnvzxRjMeysOp/)

`reduce` is just too good.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>97</s> <s>94</s> 87 bytes

- -3 thanks to Unrelated String
- -7 thanks to c--

Uses uppercase as the challenge only states case-insensitive.

```c
f(char*s){for(int a[96]={},i=64;i<90;)*s?a[*s++&95]++:a[++i]&&printf("%c:%d ",i,a[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9BTsMwELznFYOlRo5tpB6gUmoCVx7ALcrBOEnrksbBdlsgytuD0yIuq52dndlZfb/Tep5bqvfKMZ@NrXXU9AGqzDdVMU7CFJsHaZ7ytcyYf1El85yn@WPF@VaVnJsqTQcXFS0lK71d1SDCCFWaKpPTvDgdlenp2Zo6w5gAyyEwX0bziADy2nSdFbhY19V3RNyGb/sGnyejP/Du7KVHa79wOB2HpoY9Nw4h8p36@UZtd/5PtI51EmAsyCS2yyeh8BIRYzgFTwnJbhmA/8gexXOMHJcyeWVaygLnVzAl0/wL)

Ungolfed:

```c
f(char*s){
  for(int a[96]={},i=64;
      i<90;) // for all characters in string, then from 'A' to 'Z':
    *s? // done processing string?
      a[*s++&95]++: // no, uppercase letter and increment count
      a[++i]&&printf("%c:%d ",i,a[i]); // yes, print counts
}
```

Comment: `a[255]` should be `a[256]`?

Comment: If uppercase is allowed, [95](https://tio.run/##PU7LTsMwELznKwZLjfxCAkQrFRPOfAC3KIfgJK0hjYPttkCUbw9Og3pZ7czs7Iy@3Wk9TQ3V@9JxzwbTBZT5w3pTZMMoTbZ5VI11VHGvWJlzL0S6XRdCLKwQ5nl7r8rcFGnau2huKFnpp1UFIo2cecbUOM1fD6Xp6MmaimFIgDkQ3OcxJyKAvNZtayXO1rXVDZEL@bav8XU0@hPvzp47NPYbH8dDX1ewp9ohRL0tf39Q2Z3/N93FOUpwHlQS17loyLxCxOiPwVNC2NIBuHb2yF5i53jE1EVpKA9CXMCYjNMf)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -n, 37 bytes

```perl
for$l(a..z){/$l/i&&say"$l ".s/$l//gi}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glRyNRT69Ks1pfJUc/U02tOLFSSSVHQUmvGCSgn55Z@/@/R2pOTr6OQnl@UU6K4r/8gpLM/Lzi/7p5vmWmeoYGAA)

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, <s>85</s> 82 bytes

<sup>Saved 3 bytes thanks to [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258761/counting-letters-in-a-string/258876?noredirect=1#comment571179_258876)</sup>

```
=LET(c,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),q,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),c,)),FILTER(c&"="&q,q))
```

The `LET()` function allows you to assign variables to values and reference them by name later. Every term is a pair except the last which is the output.

- `c,CHAR(ROW(65:90))` creates an array of the strings `A` through `Z`.
- `q,LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(a),c,))` creates an array of how many times each letter appears by measuring the length of the input vs. the length if we replace that letter with nothing. `SUBSTITUTE()` is case-sensitive so we transform the input to uppercase.
- `FILTER(c&"="&q,q)` combines the array of letters with the count of each character and then filter for just those where the count (`q`) was truthy (anything not zero).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If OP doesn't require tupples and uppercase answers are allowed, then maybe remove the 1st variable and nest it inside `SUBSTITUTE()`: `=LET(x,CHAR(ROW(65:90)),y,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),x,)),FILTER(x&"="&y,y))` for 82 bytes.

Comment: @JvdV Good point. I usually write `LET()` functions for PPCG in their long form and then cut it down. I overlooked the fact that `LEN()` doesn't care about case so I wasn't saving bytes*2 with the variable.

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 62 bytes

```powershell
$args-match'[a-z]'|%{"$_"|% *l*r}|group|%{,($_.Name,$_.Count)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYy9DoIwFEZ3nuKmqVYN5Q1MTNgcnNyMIRULiKUXb4v4A7464uKs05d8J@fU2GpyhTZGpkh64NnyOXBFuZOV8mkhdko@9qKbPBlPWDeBhVlQ3@WETT2e4Ywn0UZVOhw3xsb6eT/0QcCdJ1gC@4QRWiRzZMGUZ7D6gA5itFdNfoty7dCCjLGqSTsXMPZ1t4WGS3NKz3AgbC1keIOyqWoHOLrgR2zU4w5HzP9tCxBRJF5ClniyQvxkD28)

```powershell
$args-match'[a-z]'        # For each character argument, exclude non letters characters
|%{"$_"|% *l*r}           # Converts to lowercase
|group                    # Groups them
|%{,($_.Name,$_.Count)}   # build pairs of letters and counts
```

Comment: *Love* the solution, but it's missing a sort, unfortunately.

Comment: @BrunoBrant The output seems sorted by characters already, it looks like `group` does it by default. Do you have a failing test case that I could try?

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>38</s> 29 bytes

```
T`Llp`ll_
O`.
(.)\1*
$1, $.&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnpyAhJyeeyz9Bj0tDTzPGUItLxVBHQUVP7dC2//89UnNy8nUUyvOLclIUAQ) Output includes trailing newlines. Saved 9 bytes thank to @FryAmTheEggman. Explanation:

```
T`Llp`ll_
```

Convert letters to lower case and delete all other printable ASCII.

```
O`.
```

Sort the characters.

```
(.)\1*
$1, $.&¶
```

Output the count of each letter.

Previous 38-byte version worked with any input, not just printable ASCII:

```
T`L`l
O`.
M!`([a-z])\1*
(.)\1*
$1, $.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnIYfLP0GPy1cxQSM6UbcqVjPGUItLQw9MqRjqKKjoqf3/75Gak5Ovo1CeX5SToggA) Explanation:

```
T`L`l
```

Lowercase the input string.

```
O`.
```

Sort the characters.

```
M!`([a-z])\1*
```

Extract the runs of identical letters.

```
(.)\1*
$1, $.&
```

Output the count of each letter.

<s>31</s> 30 bytes in [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1:

```
.
$L
O`.
L$`([a-z])\1*
$1, $.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X49LxYfLP0GPy0clQSM6UbcqVjPGUItLxVBHQUVP7f9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA) Explanation:

```
.
$L
```

Lowercase the input.

```
O`.
```

Sort the characters.

```
L$`([a-z])\1*
```

For each run of identical letters...

```
$1, $.&
```

... output the count of each letter.

Comment: It seems you can [save a bit](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnIYfLP0GPKzouUbcqlotLQ08zxlCLS8VQQUVPTSXv/3@P1JycfB2F8vyinBRFAA) by removing the bad characters instead of keeping the good ones.

Comment: Perhaps [a few more](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnpyAhJyeeyz9Bj0tDTzPGUItLxVBHQUVPTSXv/3@P1JycfB2F8vyinBRFAA) by using `T` more.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 68 bytes

```
s=>s.toLowerCase(m={}).match(/[a-z]/g).sort().map(l=>m[l]=-~m[l])&&m
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>s.toLowerCase(m={}).match(/[a-z]/g).sort().map(l=>m[l]=-~m[l])&&m

;[
  'hello world',
  'The tuick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
].forEach(s=>console.log(f(s)))
```

### UPD 73 -> 68

Thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) for the tips ([one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258761/counting-letters-in-a-string/258779?noredirect=1#comment571012_258779), [two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258761/counting-letters-in-a-string/258779?noredirect=1#comment571013_258779)) to reduce bytes count

Comment: `(m[l]||0)+1` can be `-~m[l]`

Comment: Oh, and you can initialise `m` within `toLowerCase()` to save another byte.

Comment: _Actually_, assigning the RegEx to `m` rather than using an explicit object should work, too.

Comment: @Shaggy You mean `m=/[a-z]/g`?

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
álÐ¢øê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MKcwxMOLTq84/Cq//@jlTyUdJRSgTgHivOBGAQVgLgcyi@CyqUAsaJSLAA)

Input as a list of characters.

**Alternative 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer with input as a string:** (suggested by *@KevinCruijssen*)

```
ál{Åγø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MKc6sOt5zYf3vH/v0dqTk6@jkJ5flFOiiIA)

*-3 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
á       # Filter for alphabetic characters only
 lÐ     # Convert to lowercase and triplicate
   ¢    # Count the occurences of each character
    øê  # Zip, sort, and uniquify
```

```python
á       # Filter for alphabetic characters only
 l{     # Convert to lowercase and sort
   Åγ   # Run-length encode the string
     ø  # Zip
```

Comment: `ʒa}` is the builtin `á`. :) Also, you can remove the `S` by taking the input as a list of characters: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MKcwxMOLTq84/Cq//@jlTyUdJRSgTgHivOBGAQVgLgcyi@CyqUAsaJSLAA). Or if you prefer to keep the input as string, here is a 6 bytes alternative using the run-length encode builtin: `ál{Åγø`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, updated!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>185</s> ... 134 bytes

```pascal
var c,d:char;s:string;i:word;begin;read(s);for c:=^to^do begin;i:=0;for d in upcase(s)do i+=ord(c=d);if i>0then writeln(c,i)end;end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BDsIgEEXjNVzNssRqumaCR2mCM9MyCYEG0B4fiS7@6r28f/hKPt63g3r/@AI0s6XgC1ZbW9G0o9ozF8aX7JqwiOepGtzyUK1bLy2vV87wp2rd8kMMmuB9kK8y7MH15kZkIscGdQN9Li1IgrNok5gmmtVIYhx79B4kxgzjNfIX) (134b, courtesy of @michael-tkach)

<sub><s>[150b](https://tio.run/##JY7BDsIgEER/ZY80QdOLJkLwX3B3abch0ADaz0esh7m8eZPM7iv6eAk79v7xBVCTrqa2Immxojdz5EL2xYskW9iTqpMNucBm3P3WMjxmyvCv0Thci9omK8bNp0UgCd47@spjOEwJgI6grZxGhUqGHECe80mOIo1jUqgH50S/XHtfOcYM40ikLw)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[155b](https://tio.run/##JY7BDsIgEER/ZY80qaYXTYTgv@AulG0INAvaz0esh7m8eZPM7iq6dAk79v5xAlXXJpxXgzNpjE4Mz5s@ipB5@ZWzEe9I1cmEIrBpe7@1Ao@FCvxr1BajqG0yrO1yWgSc4b2jq34Mh8kB0BK06POoUPGQA/BzOckh3HzKCufBfaZfrr1Hn1KBcSTRFw)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[160b](https://tio.run/##JY7BDsIgEETvfsUe21hN9dBECP4L7kLZhoBZiP18xHqYy5s3ybxtQRsv/o2tfaxAUaUKp1XjRAqDFc3TpvYspF9u5aTFWRrKqH0W2JS51Qz3hfLp36IyGGTYzo9l1KzMfHgEnCDm3Qna4vq6@@wBDUENLvUWB@6@B37OB9mFq4tpwKlzl@iXa2vBxZihv4n0BQ)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[161b](https://tio.run/##HY6xDoMwDER3vsJbQaIV7dAhVvovqW3AKEpQEpXPTwPDLe/dSbe7TM7f551q/bkE2eSSNCxIIxtaXUIdN3PExPiVRUNHxt7cDZM47vOAc0ywGfssEV5vjnCVUI2dLsWgAXw8JJHL0gYcO52BLENZJTRLvQ7YkH6mixxJi/jQ03jypmlACXzmUesq3kdodzz/AQ)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[162b](https://tio.run/##JY7BDoIwEETvfsXegAQNZxr8l7K7hdXaYlup@vO1wcNc3uRNZtMRtT2bDUvZdYDYY09jTEHcomTMPpCaeRGnAmtqY6eMD4AgrtEzEptlldvdPpzfniGm157fn29D/vSXZJyGw6BqgPWZA@rIdYc8iAGcCNLKrrbYSqcqkutwkBwksXUt9tKxI1VzKWVlaz3UW5Z@)</s></sub>
 <sub><s>[185b](https://tio.run/##JczBDoIwDMbxV@kNSNBwMB624LuUrkB1bthNUF8eQQ89fP9f0gkToT/0E63rjApYJ5OyShgs1c7QiGrFSMjnk@14kGCV0ZWpssm0Pi6shIn3jaYtsCPH/TDK9ebvIU4PTfk5L6/3p7B9VCCQAAguwv@XmLb5gdsh7SA9uJYgjxy2RqVUdktyaf5pUcnsQ0n1Bhzcfsd1Hdn7CEtU774)</s></sub>

Iterates over the alphabet and the input string `s`, comparing chars `d` and `c`. The `for <char> in <string>` syntax was handy. Implemented some of the [Pascal golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240117/tips-for-golfing-in-pascal).

Comment: You may get 134 with those little tricks... https://tio.run/##JY1BDsIgEEXjNVzNssRqumaCR2mCM9MyCYEG0B4fiS7@6r28f/hKPt63g3r/@AI0s6XgC1ZbW9G0o9ozF8aX7JqwiOepGtzyUK1bLy2vV87wp2rd8kMMmuB9kK8y7MH15kZkIscGdQN9Li1IgrNok5gmmtVIYhx79B4kxgzjNfIX

Answer (score 4):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 23 bytes

```
YSSLCaFiUQy@XL;Pi.(iNy)
```

How?

```
YSSLCaFiUQy@XL;Pi.(iNy)  : One arg; str
     a                   : First input
   LC                    : To lowercase
 SS                      : Sort
Y                        : Yank
      Fi                 : For i in
        UQy              : Unique values of y
           @XL           : Only lowercase alphabet characters
               P           : Print
                i          : Letter
                 .         : Concatenated with
                   iN      : Letter in
                     y     : Input
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZU1NMQ2FGaVVReUBYTDtQaS4oaU55KSIsIiIsIiIsIlwiVGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveCBqdW1wcyBvdmVyIHRoZSBsYXp5IGRvZ1wiIl0=)

Comment: This works on the current test cases, but the challenge specifies that *all* non-letter characters should be ignored, not just spaces. I think looping over `z` and adding some logic to skip letters whose count is zero will be your best bet.

Comment: @DLosc Sorry about that! This should work? Lmk if there're any more problems :)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica (Wolfram Language), 34 bytes

```
KeySort@*LetterCounts@*ToLowerCase
```

TIO.run is in the comments below. Edited to save 4 bytes thanks to a suggestion from ZaMoC.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcw7DoMwDADQq1iM3KFSpI5lQCpb1cEFE1JI3DoOn17eZXzLi6gTRdTQo/mL3ei4s6irG1IluXJJml3dccPbScxkrYSk4Pyj6iaCbwn9DC/hLcHIO7xL/GTglQTOGBb8HTCwr55mfw "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") here you are... ;)

Comment: I just got it to work on TIO, but your answer is shorter. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, in order to avoid [] you can also use KeySort@LetterCounts@ToLowerCase@#& for 35 bytes. But in this case you can "chain" 3 functions using @* for 1 extra byte.

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought about the operator form. Thanks for your suggestion. I did that on my answer to this related question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258558/the-number-of-distinct-words-in-a-sentence/

Comment: It's strange that LetterCounts works fine on tio.run, but WordCounts causes an error. (WordCounts is used in the answer to the question in the previous comment.) I guess WordCounts uses some NLP, but that isn't needed for just counting letters.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 34 bytes

```arturo
$=>[match lower&{/\pL}|tally|sort]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?CKEWco)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 82 bytes

Probably takes *a list of pairs* a bit too literally... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```javascript
s=>[...s.toLowerCase()].sort().join``.match(/([a-z])\1*/g).map(s=>[s[0],s.length])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxEoIwEEDR3lNkqBJHFj0ANraWdpgZIgQChixmAyiXj9ja/je/V7OiyndjSB3WOjZ5pPxcAABBwCsu2l8UaS4kEPrABfTYubKEQYXK8IwXKl2luJ/2WSu2OPLfTsVRHgisdm0wUsQKHaHVYLHlDU@MthbZgt7WiRC7P70ZzV5TVz3Zw@PiWINv1k/DSAxn7VnY2Kr1w2pstzt@AQ)

Comment: `s.split(c)` is not right. You take into account the case of letters when separating. Because of this for `The tuick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` your function outputs only `2 t` instead of `3 t`

Comment: @EzioMercer You're right. Updated to a new method.

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##Xcu7DoIwGIbh3atoGEibSLkCXFwd3QgJtfycrP2w5aAYvfWKq9M7PHl7NSuvXTeMiUVFoc6Czw65lNLLEScs5I7KE0f2eotCeriRC9mjs2UpHQ1GaeJprpK1SJv9tiL3RZZ8fhFxjKBhPQxJg4bXPGrJGLAFzlSRELs/PbfE7lOnr@zisFhW48H66TZ4hpkcGzc2an2yCs12hy8)

Comment: @Shaggy I decided to return a list and there's already an answer using an object, so I'll stick to that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
⭆¹ΦＥβ⟦λ№↧θλ⟧§λ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaBjqKLhl5pSkFmmAeEk6CtE5OgrO@aVART755alFyYnFqRqFmjoKOZqxQNKxxDMvJbVCA6jIUBMIrP//90jNycnXUSjPL8pJUeT6r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    β           Predefined variable lowercase alphabet
   Ｅ            Map over letters
      λ         Current letter
     ⟦     ⟧    Make into tuple with
       №        Count of
          λ     Current letter in
         θ      Input string
        ↧       Lowercased
  Φ             Filtered where
            §λ¹ Count was nonzero
⭆¹              Pretty-print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J9.4](https://www.jsoftware.com), 35 bytes

```
'\pL'(~.,:<@#/.~)@/:~@rxall tolower
```

## [J903](https://www.jsoftware.com), 37 bytes

```
'[a-z]'(~.,:<@#/.~)@/:~@rxall tolower
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxU1U9OlG3KlZdo05Px8rGQVlfr07TQd-qzqGoIjEnR6EkPye_PLUIqthNkys1OSPfIU3NTkE9IzUnJ1-hPL8oJ0XdWj0kI1WhsDQzOVshqSi_PE8hLb9CIas0t6BYIb8stUihBCidk1hVqZCSn64OMW3BAggNAA)

Explanation is the same, but the PCRE engine was updated which makes the regex 2 bytes shorter.

```
'\pL'(~.,:<@#/.~)@/:~@rxall tolower
                            tolower  NB. lowercase the input
'\pL'                 rxall          NB. match every letter
                  /:~@               NB. then sort
     (          )@                   NB. then invoke a monadic fork
            #/.~                     NB. count the occurrences of each letter
          <@                         NB. then box each result
      ~.                             NB. uniquify the matches
        ,:                           NB. stack matches on top of counts
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$18\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 14.82 bytes

```
UgAzsAqkztcsZZZUz:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhabQtMdq4odC7OrSpKLo6KiQqusIBJQ-QVrPVJzcvJ1FMrzi3JSFCGCAA)

##### Explanation

```python
U           # Lowercase
 gAzsAqk    # Alphabetic characters only
        zt  # Triplicate
cs          # Counts of each
  ZZ        # Zip
    ZU      # Uniquify
      z:    # Sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 32 bytes

```
(u:97+i.26)(e.#[;"+1#.=/)tolower
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmtxU0Gj1MrSXDtTz8hMUyNVTznaWknbUFnPVl-zJD8nvzy1CKrOTZMrNTkj3yFNzU5BPSM1JydfoTy_KCdF3Vo9JCNVobA0MzlbIakovzxPIS2_QiGrNLegWCG_LLVIoQQonZNYVamQkp-uDjFtwQIIDQA)

`u:97+i.26` A character vector of all lowercase letters.
`tolower` Input converted to lowercase.
`(u:97+i.26)(...)tolower` Apply inner function with lowercase alphabet as left argument and lowercased string as right argument.
`=/` Equality table.
`1#.` Sum each row. This gives a vector of length 26 with the count of each letter in the input.
`[;"+` Pair up each letter with its count.
`e.#` Only keep the pairs where the letter is an element of the input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>15</s> 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
v r\L ü ËÎ+DÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=diByXEwg/CDLzitEyg&input=IlRoZSBxdWljayBicm93biBmb3gganVtcHMgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2ciCi1S)

-2 by Shaggy

Outputs a list of “ab” strings where a is the character and b is the number of occurrences

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü ËÎ+DÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CDLzitEyg&input=ImFiY2FhYSIgLVE)

Doesn’t remove non-letters

Made on My iPhone

```
ü ËÎ+DÊ # input string
ü       # list of same characters grouped together
  Ë     # map each string of same char to:
   Î    #   the character
    +DÊ #   append length of group
```

Comment: Note that the challenge requires the counting of letters _only_ and that the output be sorted by character.

Comment: @Shaggy Oops, forgot to read the rules lol

Comment: [13 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=diByXEwg/CDLzitEyg&input=IlRoZSBxdWljayBicm93biBmb3gganVtcHMgb3ZlciB0aGUgbGF6eSBkb2ciCi1S) in v2.

Comment: @Shaggy Only took you 20 seconds to golf mine! Thanks

Comment: You might be able to pass the `v` as an argument to `ü` instead to save a byte but we'll need clarification on whether the output _must_ be lowercase or if it can be mixed case.

Comment: @Shaggy that was my first thought as well, but I didn’t think the output was right. I also thought of filtering out pairs containing non-alphanumeric characters after mapping, but it’s  a bit longer than doing it before

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒlḟŒuṢŒr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJyHO@YfnVT6cOeio5OK/h9uPzrp4c4ZmpH//ytlAJXkK5TnF@WkKOkoKIVkpCoUlmYmZyskFeWX5ymk5VcoZJXmFhQr5JelFimUAKVzEqsqFVLy05UA)

At least slightly less boring than if I'd used `Øa`. Feels ever so vaguely beatable, still...

```
Œl          The lowercased input,
  ḟŒu       with elements of the uppercased input filtered out.
     ṢŒr    Sort and run-length encode.
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pascal, <s>590</s> 358 bytes

This full `program` requires a processor supporting features of ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.
Furthermore,

- the *implementation-dependent* behavior of the selection order in a `for … in` set member iteration statement must be *ascending*,
- the *implementation-defined* default `TotalWidth` for `integer`-type `write` arguments must be sufficiently large in order to leave some space between a character and the number, and
- the *implementation-defined* set of available characters contains both upper and lowercase characters.

The GPC ([GNU Pascal Compiler](https://www.GNU-Pascal.de/)) fulfills these conditions on an x86‑64 Linux system if compiling with the `‑‑extended-pascal` option.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var c:char;f:array[char]of integer value[otherwise 0];begin while not EOF do begin read(c);c:=(c+'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')[index('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',c)+1];f[c]:=f[c]+1 end;for c in['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']do if 0<f[c]then writeLn(c,f[c])end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program letterFrequency(input, output);
    var
        c: char;
        letterFrequency: array[char] of integer value [otherwise 0];
    begin
        while not EOF(input) do
        begin
            { `read(input, c)` is equivalent to `c := input^; get(input)`. }
            read(input, c);
            
            { There is no built-in “change case” function as Pascal does not
              guarantee the coexistence of lower and uppercase letters. The EP
              function `index(source, pattern)` returns the index of the first
              occurence of `pattern` in `source`. If `pattern` is not found,
              zero is returned. Remember, `string` indices are 1-based, thus
              add `1` to select the prepended value of `c`. }
            c := (c + 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
                [index('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', c) + 1];
            
            letterFrequency[c] := letterFrequency[c] + 1;
        end;
        
        for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
            'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'] do
        begin
            if letterFrequency[c] > 0 then
            begin
                writeLn(c, letterFrequency[c]);
            end;
        end;
    end.
```

See also [FreePascal implementation](/a/258872/94076).

Comment: “Pascal does not guarantee that the characters 'a' through 'z' are arranged in contiguous order.” — Ok, Pascal does not, but what about you? `q:=Pos(c,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');if q>0then c:='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[q];`

Comment: @manAtWork Thanks for essentially reminding me of [this golfing tip](/a/254108/94076). I have adapted it to Extended Pascal, that means using the standardized `index`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->s{[*s.upcase.chars.tally.slice(*?A..?Z).sort]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3DXTtiqujtYr1SguSE4tT9ZIzEouK9UoSc3Iq9YpzMpNTNbTsHfX07KM09Yrzi0pia6H6XAsU0qLVM1JzcvIVyvOLclLUY7nAQiEZqQqFpZnJ2QpJRfnleQpp-RUKWaW5BcUK-WWpRQolQOmcxKpKhZT8dPVYiGELFkBoAA)

Comment: No need to use outer splat. `->s{s.upcase.chars.tally.slice(*?A..?Z).sort}` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

### Common Lisp, 110 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(reduce(lambda(s c &aux(e(assoc c s)))(if e(prog1 s(incf(cdr e)))(acons c 1 s)))s :initial-value()))
```

The ungolfed version is:

```
(defun frequencies (string)
  (reduce (lambda (map char)
            (let ((entry (assoc char map)))
              (if entry
                  (prog1 map
                    (incf (cdr entry)))
                  (acons char 1 map))))
          string
          :initial-value nil))
```

For example:

```
> (frequencies "abcbad")
((#\d . 1) (#\c . 1) (#\b . 2) (#\a . 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 19 bytes

```
el_'{,97>--$e`{W%}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T81J169WsfS3E5XVyU1oTpctVb1f62Vm3W0UkZqTk6@Qnl@UU6KkoJSSEaqQmFpZnK2QlJRfnmeQlp@hUJWaW5BsUJ@WWqRQglQOiexqlIhJT9dKbY63k1JQddOQSlGW7tW1U/rPwA)

Returns strings in the form of `{char}{count}`

## Explanation

```
el_'{,97>--$e`{W%}% # a function taking an input string
el_      --         # remove all elements of the input which do not occur in
   '{,97>           # the character range lowercase a-z
           $        # sort
            e`      # run-length encode (1h1e2l as an example)
              {W%}% # to meet the output specification of {char}{count} and not {count}{char}
                    # we reverse each of the arrays in this sorted array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>75</s> 71 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3852/lynn)*

```haskell
f s=[(l,n)|(u,l)<-zip['A'..'Z']['a'..],n<-[sum[1|c<-s,l==c||u==c]],n>0]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN93TFIptozVydPI0azRKdXI0bXSrMgui1R3V9fTUo9Rjo9UTgaxYnTwb3eji0txow5pkG91inRxb2-SamlIgGQuUszOIhRqXkJuYmadgq5CSz6WgUFCUmVeioKKQpqDkAbQzX0chPL8oJ0VRCVUuJCNVobA0MzlbIakovzxPIS2_QiGrNLegWCG_LLVIoQQonZNYVQk0M11PCWIPzPkA)

#### Explanation

List comprehensions seem to be shorter than `map` and `filter`.

```haskell
f s=
```

Define our function, `f`, which takes a string `s`.

```haskell
zip['A'..'Z']['a'..]
```

Create a list of (uppercase letter, lowercase letter) tuples.

```haskell
(u,l)<-___
```

For each uppercase letter `u` and lowercase letter `l` in that list...

```haskell
,n<-sum[1|c<-s,l==c||u==c]
```

Let `n` be the number of characters `c` in `s` for which `c` equals one of `l` and `u`...

```haskell
[(l,n)|____,n>0]
```

Return a list of tuples of `l` and the corresponding `n` where `n` is greater than `0`.

---

A solution using `toLower` from `Data.Char` comes in at **76 bytes**:

```haskell
import Data.Char
f s=[(l,n)|l<-['a'..'z'],n<-[sum[1|c<-s,l==toLower c]],n>0]
```

Comment: Slightly shorter is `f s=[(l,n)|(u,l)<-zip['A'..'Z']['a'..],n<-[sum[1|c<-s,c==u||c==l]],n>0]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 51 bytes

```julia
~s=(x='A':'Z';y=@.sum(in(x=>x+32),s);(x.=>y)[y.>0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcm7DsIgFADQ3a@46QJEQ3xsNhD9ByeNQ7VoqZRboVhw6K9jN9dz2mB0tYk5T17QKMiR7MmZlEkcuA8d1XZGGZe7LVt5VtLIhUzskrhcX1nunbaDsXQqGmUMwojO1AVb/P3UKHgHfX/BzeFo4YER2tD1HvCjHAxzm@qboMZnwfIP)

- Thanks to MarcMush for the following:

  1. replace `sum(==(x),uppercase(s))` with `sum(in(x=>x+32),s)`
  2. replace Tuples with Pairs (e.g., `(a,b)` vs. `a=>b`).

### 54 byte solution

```julia
~s=(y='A':'Z'.|>x->x=>sum(in(x=>x+32),s))[@.last(y)>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcm7DsIgFIDh3ac46QJEbbxsJhB9ByeNQ7VoqadQuVgwpq@O3dz@fH8bUFXrmPPoOE2cHMiOnEj5FXEpIhcudFRpOlWcbzds4Rg770usnKeJidUl91Zpj5qORSMRDQzGYl2w2d@PjYRXULcnXK0ZNNxNhDZ0vQPzlhb8tLH6JKjNo2D5Bw)

### 55 byte solution

```julia
~s=[x=>y for x='A':'Z' for y=sum(in(x=>x+32),s) if y>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYy7DsIgFEB3v@KmCxAdfGwmNOk/OGkcqqWWesutUCw49NeRuDiec5LTe9T1LqS0OHkJsozQkoUgWcWO7Mx@FKXzA9eG5x7Wh73YOAG6hVhur2m02kxo@FJ0CpFgJotNIVZ/f@oUvLy@P@FmaTZ5GaD3w@iA3srClDPWnwgNPQqRvg)

- Thanks to Kirill L. for suggesting [comprehensions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions) and [generator expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Generator-Expressions)!

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I was including the assignment in the header, since I've seen other examples of that. I've now moved it to back to the code and updated the byte count.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/WNeuOL@oRCMtM6cktUgjszgntQTI0NEotC0tKEgtSk4sTtUo1tR81LGqUFNTr8auQtdOo0KnuDRXw9ZWo0JTByj6/z8A "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online") would be fine, since it is an anonymous function, and the header is just to store it, but what you did was a snippet, not a function (not valid Julia code by itself). If other answers are not valid, I try to point it out (not many people check Julia answers)

Comment: It is probably golfable further, but [this](https://tio.run/##RYyxDsIgFAB3v@KFBUg66GqCif/gZNMBW2qplEehWHDor2Pj4nh3yY3RaHlKpWxB1CxVmUOPHpKgV3qmd/qjLOoQJyYES7yKzinfyqBY4LzRPeTLsSnOa7sYyzYyKGMQVvSmI/zw97dBwRx1@4KHx9Xu4wRjnFwAfCsPy56N/GTo8El4@QI) works for 62 bytes

Comment: I [golfed one byte off your solution](https://tio.run/##RYyxDsIgFAB3v@KFBUg66GqCif/gZOOALbXU14KPYsGhv46Ni@PdJTdEtPqQSlmDqkWqsoTOESTFz/zIr/xHWYU4CqVEklX03lCjgxFBSrAd5NP@VjzZacZJrKw3iA4WR9gyufv7S2/gFW3zhDu5Zdq@CYY4@gDubQjmLaP@ZGjdg8nyBQ). Here's [another 62 byte solution](https://tio.run/##RckxDoIwFADQ3VP8sLQ/IY2ukhq5g5OEAaFKsdDaUmkZuHplc31v8Eo2p5DS5jgNnJTkTO6kiPzKnB8p3xFzb4ywbeMEdYhFtUpDQx6RMVZXkV2ONSZj5TSriW5ZL5TSsGirugwPf7/1Aj5etm94WL1M8NQBBj8aB/orLMx7q2aN0OlXhukH).

Comment: -6 bytes by avoiding the way too long `uppercase` and using Pairs instead of Tuples [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcm7DsIgFIDh3ac46QJEbbxsJhB9ByeNQ7VoqadQuVgwpq@O3dz@fH8bUFXrmPPoOE2cHMiOnEj5FXEpIhcudFRpOlWcbzds4Rg770usnKeJidUl91Zpj5qORSMRDQzGYl2w2d@PjYRXULcnXK0ZNNxNhDZ0vQPzlhb8tLH6JKjNo2D5Bw "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: @MarcMush Brilliant! I can improve several of my other posts with those suggestions. I used your ideas to trim 11 bytes off my 62 byte solution, so now it's the best so far.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel (ms365), 87 bytes

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,CHAR(ROW(97:122)),y,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),x,)),FILTER(HSTACK(x,y),y))
```

And 83 bytes if you don't want tupples, but a concatenation would do:

```
=LET(x,CHAR(ROW(97:122)),y,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),x,)),FILTER(x&"-"&y,y))
```

Answer (score 2):

And any other shell that supports `${var,,}` to downcase.

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 35 bytes

```bash
grep -o [a-z]<<<${*,,}|sort|uniq -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBBN18hOlG3KtbGxkalWktHp7amOL@opKY0L7NQQTf5////afn5SYlFhgpu/v5OjkGKAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 16+ (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 166 bytes

Tried to use only inline stream as a different approach, but couldn't beat the best Java answer.

```java
s->s.toLowerCase().chars().distinct().filter(e->e>96&e<123).sorted().mapToObj(e->new String[]{(char)e+"",s.toLowerCase().chars().filter(o->o==e).count()+""}).toList()
```

[JDoodle   (because TIO currently only supports Java up to v12)](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/FjF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>112</del> 108 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to the comment of @Kirill L.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVA9T8MwEN3zK04dGnuxxBqRSKUzUykDCEWOc0lcLrZrOzQB9bcHl26M7@Pee7qgJMlVj876COEGhLJEqKK2RoxTlA1hltnmlCh4ltrATwbQYgdjAkz6PhSw814u74fotek/eAFHoyOUf04Al9hIhnVsMyCRhYv11G44/6@@DAjnSatPaLy9GOjsDKdpdAHsF3qISSb5vUBr@/v1db3t6Fgo7tW8DCLao3Po9zKg6DRF9EyVlarKfJdvt@qxzN9yLnpvJ/e0sLmsZi5G6V4lTRhYLQhNHweecg54FiG9JdlqUT/w9br@Ag)

```scala
def f(s:String)=s.toUpperCase.filter(c=>c>='A'&&c<='Z').groupBy(x=>x).mapValues(_.length).toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZExb8IwEIX3/IonBnDUyiorKkiULh2YKB2KEDLGIaaOHRwbmlb57alDolQdOtl@9/Tuu3PBmWJ1LbPcWIeieVFulBLcSaNp5h3bKxFFZn8KEpZManxHwEEkyMKDMHssJphby8rNylmpj9t4grWWDtObE8iD6pQmiRVnLzQvySAVShlcjVWHQRz/53pNBc5e8g/srblqJOYTJ5/lBcxFWLhQVuyrxMEc25Qq6tB@QwJcixWoVuK8IYuU2Xu8aBdve8ILU/B5LixnhWgMRSgV1Jl1Iy6C2Nu48do15W41dMlyKrLclZs@eUuv0qXPImFeuTemvCAPcXSL@NuFJsYKxlPCMZ11LIBMEITZFKP5CMMhOB7D/X0U9w50GITHuJti3MnV7ay6Vq0lDBHGpkX43qeS7Ohu3C6qiur6Bw)

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(frequency("hello world"))
    println(frequency("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
  }

  def frequency(s: String): Seq[(Char, Int)] = {
    val uppercaseChars = s.toUpperCase
    val counts = mutable.Map.empty[Char, Int].withDefaultValue(0)

    uppercaseChars.foreach(c => {
      if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        counts(c) += 1
      }
    })

    counts.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Scala, but I think `identity` can be replaced by `x=>x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 21 bytes

```
*.lc.comb(/<:L>/).Bag
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxDoIwFAXQX7khxIIxZXNQYXB2dCeltAUtPmxBrMZvr8znjMrZfRwCNhpl3HIruaShyYrT4VIVOT8LE4/wIiBJa5QVvjpL65yb3k@/BJocWKesJSzkbMt2YNdO4Tn38o7G0fJYzxu3eRg96KUcppWt@AS0ZFj8Aw)

- `.lc` converts the input string to lowercase.
- `.comb(/<:L>/)` produces a list of all non-overlapping matches for the regex `<:L>` (a letter) in that string.
- `.Bag` converts that list to a Bag, a set with multiplicity, which is also an associative mapping and thus allowed as a return value per comments added to the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
FNS{rzZI&<"`"N <N"{"(N /rzZN)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/380vuLqoKspTzUYpQclPwcZPqVpJw09BHyjmp/n/f0hGqkJhaWZytkJSUX55nkJafoVCVmluQbFCfllqkUIJUDonsapSISU/HQA)

##### Explanation

Used a for loop `F` to iterate over the letters which are valid by
**I&<"`"N <N"{"** which checks if a letter in the string is within *backtick* and *open curly bracket*.

**rzZ** - converts the input string in lower i.e. `input().lower()` in Python.

**S{** - used to sort the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 77 bytes

```lua
s=...for i=65,90 do c=s.char(i)_,n=s:upper():gsub(c,c)f=n>0 and print(c,n)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCoAgEADAr@xRQaRLQcF27gcdw9RKkFXWfP/WHCd3J9LQWnsVhoTTaOYBQgGPzfrHsUr6MIRt6bVGVnq5Wz@VN15fSOsAjgJUTvT@RzpSEJEt5lxgL5zDBw)

```lua
s=...                        -- Take argument as input
for i=65,90 do
    c=s.char(i)              -- Get the char represented by charcode i
    _,n=s:upper():gsub(c,c)  -- n stores the number of occurrences of char c
    f=n>0 and print(c,n)     -- if n>0, print char/count pair
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 56 bytes

```r
\(s,a=el(strsplit(tolower(s),"")))table(a[a%in%letters])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCsJAEEV7TzEsBHYh9mlS2HkAO7XYmFmNjpk4O2vUq9hEwUN5GwOm-vAe7z9fMrxD-Uka5sW32NiY-xLJRpXYUaNWmbhHsdHlxjjn1FeE1q991rQZoSpK3LqpXwRrlkjE0LNQbdxsBKsDwiU1uxNUwn0LgW9wTOcuAl9RQEdN_nGHmvdmOhqG__4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes (17 nibbles)

```
=~|.@`($\$a$~/$$,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWNzVt67gUargUFPSAWMEBRCRoKKgA6RgFFYVELiCzTkFfRUVBB6IBqm_BWo_UnJx8HYXw_KKcFEWIIAA)

I could save 0.5 bytes by [returning (count, letter) pairs](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWNzVs67gUargUFPSAWMEBRCRoKKgA6RgFFYVELiCzTkFHRUEfoh6qbcFaj9ScnHwdhfD8opwURYggAA) instead of (letter, count).

#### Explanation

There's probably a better way to do this.

```
=~|.@`($\$a$~/$$,$
    @               First line of stdin
   .                Map to each character:
     `($             Lowercase
  |                 Filter by this function:
        \$a          Is the character a letter?
=~                  Group and sort by:
           $         Each letter
                    We now have the lowercase letters from the input, grouped
                    by letter (giving a list of strings) and sorted
                    For each string of identical letters (implicit):
            ~        Return a tuple of:
             /$$      The first character of the string
                ,$    The length of the string
```

The `/ ... $` idiom used in `/$$` means "[right-fold on the identity function](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/tutorial_ancillary.html#practicaltricks)," which yields the leftmost element of a list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ỊLƈṠ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKx_u7vI51vFw54IlxUnJxVDRBWs9UnNy8nUUyvOLclIUIYIA)

##### Explanation

```python
ỊLƈṠ  # Implicit input
Ị     # Remove non-alphabets
 L    # Lowercase
  ƈ   # Counts
   Ṡ  # Sort
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 116 bytes

I re-did this challenge differently by trying to do the "lowering case" and "filtering special characters" parts only by messing with the ASCII codes.

It has become quite long for a JS solution, but now i can legitimate the use of the fun `Object.entries(...)` because i'm forced to use it for the `sort` part :)

```javascript
s=>[...Buffer(s)].map(g=c=>(c=(c-64)%32+96)>96&c<123?g[c=String.fromCharCode(c)]=-~g[c]:0)&&Object.entries(g).sort()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcyxTsMwFIXhnaewKhH5qooFLYrUqg4SfQAGulUZ3BvbSXB8g@20wNBXD56Zv/@cQV1VxNBPqfTU6sXIJcr6LIR4m43RgUdoxKgmbiXKmqPkWFYv8LjdrHcV1LuqwMPzZvtqzyg/Uui9FSbQeOxUOOY/jtDI8p612T9BUbxfBo1JaJ9THbkFESkkDguSj@S0cGS54atOO0fsRsG1K4CHf3rqNPuae/xkl0A3zwx9s2Eep8joqgNLmZ36/WEt2bxe/gA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 47 bytes

```clj
#(frequencies(re-seq #"[a-z]"(.toLowerCase %)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxDsIgEADQ3a@40JjAUH/CxcHRzThQOJSKXDlAtD@PXZ1fngk0V8YuLTpwfZCOMVWMxmOWjGPGBIO46nG9CXkodKaGfNQZYa@U6monF/axhCgdiBOGQNCIgxXqny4PhFS9ecLE1CI4@sBcX0sGeiND2Tjo9QuW7lvtPw)

Returns a Map as allowed by OP in the comments. To obtain a sorted colllection this should be additionally wrapped with `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) -- 180 bytes

```rkt
#!racket
(let([s hash-set])(foldl(λ(c a)(if(hash-has-key? a c)(s a c(+ 1(hash-ref a c)))(s a c 1)))#hasheq()(map char-downcase(filter char-alphabetic?(string->list(read-line))))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBDsIgFET3noKmm08Mi17Abr2DcfGFj5AirR@06dm8g1fCljqLmcm8ZBj1QLmUtuHaDhAowyUJh8mpRPkqwY7BBPh@QAuU4C1UtpoaaOkFCi0hbQFH0e2QydZd/ono1tpuiJ4g4YGT0A5ZmXGOGhOB9SET7yOGyeGNstc9pMw@3tUp@JSBCY0KPpKsKuWMb1rv5zEaYvsKwuDS/AA)

---

### Explanation

This program returns a [hash table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html) of key-value pairs. The keys in the hash table are the characters and the values are the number of occurences in the string.

[Characters](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/characters.html) are represented by a `#\` prefix. So the string "Apple" can be thought of as:

```rkt
(display "Apple")
(display (string #\A #\p #\p #\l #\e))
```

The pseudo-code of my answer (algorithm?) is:

1. Read user input.
2. Filter only the alphabetic characters.
3. Convert all left-over characters into lowercase.
4. Iterate left-to-right using a hash table.

   1. If the hash table has the character as a key, increment the key's value.
   2. Otherwise, add a new key representing the character and set the value to 1.
5. Return the resulting hash table.

```rkt
#lang racket

(foldl (lambda (char acc)
         (if (hash-has-key? acc char)
             (hash-set acc char (add1 (hash-ref acc char)))
             (hash-set acc char 1)))
       #hasheq()
       (map char-downcase
            (filter char-alphabetic?
                    (string->list (read-line)))))
```